# Confused About Meteor this.next() Error onBeforeAction

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have the following code for a Router map:

```
this.route('confirmTag', {
    path: '/confirm-tag',
    template: 'confirmTag',
    controller: 'SignUpController',
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        if (Meteor.user()) {
            if (typeof user.profile.tag === 'undefined') {
                Router.go('confirm');
            } else {
                Router.go('checkEmail');
            }
            this.next();
        } else {
            Router.go('signUp');
        }
        this.next();
    }
});
```

Yet, I keep getting this error in console:

```
Exception in callback of async function:
.onBeforeAction@http://localhost:3000/lib/router.js?783dc96a24a92cfd09fbf0ca371d762661a830bb:87:9
```

Line 87 in the example code is:

```
if (typeof user.profile.tag === 'undefined') {
```

What or how should "this.next();" be placed in the above code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i can't imagine that calling `this.next()` is a good idea.

Comment: this.next() is actually needed when using onBeforeAction

Comment: yes, but in the true branch of your `if` you are calling it twice. But perhaps that's not a problem after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `user` defined anywhere.  What about ...

```
this.route('confirmTag', {
    path: '/confirm-tag',
    template: 'confirmTag',
    controller: 'SignUpController',
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        if (Meteor.user()) {
            var user = Meteor.user();
            if (typeof user.profile.tag === 'undefined') {
                Router.go('confirm');
            } else {
                Router.go('checkEmail');
            }
            this.next();
        } else {
            Router.go('signUp');
        }
        this.next();
    }
});
```

Comment: You're right.. I should've caught that. Got lost after staring at code for so long. Thanks!